# Dynamic dispatch implementation- virtual function table offset

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction

I'm currently in the code generation phase of building a compiler for a Java-like language. I'm trying to understand how to implement dynamic dispatch for virtual methods.

I get how to build a virtual function table for every class and store a pointer to it in every object. What I don't get is- when generating code for a function call, how do you know what the offset is for that function in the table?

Thanks.

Comment: That's a design question for your language, compiler, and binary representation.  You could consider studying the JLS and JVM specs to gain some insight into how Java does it (since you mentioned Java), but there variations and entire other alternatives.  Overall, this question is too broad to be answered here.

Comment: How do you know the offsets of a data member? How do these two problems differ?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know what anything is in your language? You write it down somewhere while parsing.

What I did in one of my toy languages was to keep a "vtable size" for each class, and when you add a new method to a class, you write down the vtable size as the offset of the method somewhere (i.e. you create a lookup table that maps method name to info about it, like its parameter types and its offset in the vtable), then add to the size to account for the newly-added method.

Of course, this assumes your language actually uses a vtable, like for example C++. If you use messaging in the style of Smalltalk or Objective-C, this table that you build actually gets saved to your compiled product and just used directly. Now a table look-up is slower than just accessing an offset directly, but also has the advantage that a caller does not need to know the type of an object to call a method on it, and you can easily add methods to objects without having to recompile the entire program.